# Redhat or linux basics?

Tags: linux

I want to learn linux and eventually get certified on it, but the problem is I'm stuck in the very beginning. Do I start with the very basics or shall I start learning redhat?

Comment: It depends upon your background and role. If you are a developer (so willing to understand how programs work, and to write new ones), read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/). If you just use Linux, you don't have to read that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a book called 'The Linux command line' that will help kick things off for you. Once you get an underlying understanding of how Linux OSs work, grasping RedHat specific operations will easier and faster.

Comment: TLCL is available as free PDF: http://www.linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php/